# What determines the quantity of MU (Mind Units) gained by a field?

Tags: ingress

When we make a fields with 3 portals in Ingress, it captures some MU (Mind Units) that will be credited to the faction count.

How is determined the quantity of MU captured, is it based :

- on the surface covered ?
- on the population density ?
- on the quantity of XM covered ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Mind Units (MU) are how the global faction scores are tallied. MU are
>   calculated based off estimations of humans within control fields.

In my experience, MU is calculated as the field surface size times population density in the area. I've built several fields over industrial zone with very low human population and it resulted in same MU score as building a similar field over a densely populated areas in the same city.

And it looks like population density information is aggregated on a very high level.

Comment: That is not entirely true, for my team covered an entire bay of water (several miles in diameter at its widest point) by grabbing portals on 3 sides right by the water, then making necessary links... We got +30k MU for that bay.

Comment: As he said: "it looks like population density information is aggregated on a very high level".  In my own city the population is  pretty much only in a few long valleys, but when I linked a large (20k-30k each side) triangle of rural farms & reserves I got a correspondingly large MU.

Comment: @Speeddymon Based on some fields I saw today -- in which a field that completely covered another field scored 20% less MU than the covered field -- it seems that the algorithm includes just multiplying by a ratio for land/sea coverage. (Not, as one might expect, calculating based on the land area under the field and treating sea as uninhabited land)